# How to display only one reading on text file from while loop

Tags: c++, ros

I would like to know on how to write only a single data in the text file as the program is currently looping from the while loop, resulting in duplicate data in my text file. For instance, I only want one reading to be shown in the text file instead of the duplicate text in my text file

**Alarm.txt**

```
2021-03-19 15:12:43 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated //How to display this reading one time

2021-03-19 15:12:49 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated //How to display this reading one time

2021-03-19 15:12:55 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated

//Afterwards, Loop every six seconds
```

**Desire output**

```
2021-03-19 15:12:43 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated //How to display this reading one time
    
2021-03-19 15:12:49 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated //How to display this reading one time
```

**Edit:**
My Code for the following

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>


const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);

    return buf;

}
ros::Rate loop_rate(main_freq_);
get_new_cmd = 1;
uart_setting();
printf("Start modbus!!\n");

while (ros::ok())
{

    if (get_new_cmd == 1)
    {

        estop_read();
           ros::Duration(0.03).sleep();
           get_new_cmd = 2; 
    }


   else if (get_new_cmd == 2)
    {

       modbus_response();
    get_new_cmd = 3;
    }




    else if (get_new_cmd == 3)
    {
    
       if (/*agv_battery < battery ||*/ points == 0)
       {
                red_light_on();
                    std::ofstream logfile("/home/amros/aiv150321/src/AlarmLog_TD02", std::ofstream::app); //or std::ofstream::app to append
            logfile << currentDateTime() << " TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated" << std::endl;         

        if (logfile.is_open())
            {
               logfile << "\n";
               logfile.close();
                    }
                    else printf("Unable to open file \n");


    
       }
        else
       {
            red_light_off();
        std::ofstream logfile("/home/amros/aiv150321/src/AlarmLog_TD02", std::ofstream::app); //or std::ofstream::app to append
        logfile << currentDateTime() << " TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated" << std::endl;

        if (logfile.is_open())
            {
               logfile << "\n";
               logfile.close();
                    }
                    else printf("Unable to open file \n");
    
           }


    
    
    get_new_cmd = 4;
           

    }




    else if (get_new_cmd == 4)
    {
        
            modbus_response();
            get_new_cmd = 1;
    }

ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();

    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;

}
```

I would be glad if someone can help me on this!Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, every time you get a "Battery alarm deactivated" or "Battery alarm activated" message, you want to overwrite the previous instance of that message, so you only ever have one of each?

(Also, you should put your `logfile << currentDateTime() << ...` inside of your `if (logfile.is_open())` or you'll be writing to an invalid file.)

Comment: @AshleyMiller Yes you are right